# exception in input in python

Tags: exception, python-3.x

When running the following code:

```
try:
   key=int(input())
except ValueError as string:
   print("Error is within:",string)
```

for example, if one puts 'rrr' this exception will rise, since 'rrr' does not support (int)

However, instead ot putting the actual string, it puts: "invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'rrr' "

How do I make it work so that the variable 'string' actually gets the wrong input that the user gave (in this example, I want it to print: 'Error is within: rrr')

Thanks a lot

Comment: small hint: just post the complete error message

Comment: I can't do so, I have to post a given message that does not include the complete error message.

Comment: Pavel meant, post the exact traceback you are getting with your current code.

Answer (score 5):

Store the input and convert it to an int separately.

```
key_str = input()
try:
    key = int(key_str)
except ValueError:
    print("Error is within:", key_str)
```

Answer (score 5):

Your issue comes from the fact that the variable `string` is the error message for a ValueError exception. If you wanted to print out the user's invalid input, you would need to create a variable that stores the user's input before your try/except. For example:

```
userInput = input()
try:
   key=int(userInput)
except ValueError:
   print("Error is within:",userInput)
```

Comment: can u redefine `input`?

Comment: @user3678068 Sure. `input` is just a name, so you can rebind it from the built-in function object to the string that function returns.

Answer (score 0):

You can just parse the error msg :D

```
print("Error is within:", string.args[0][41:-1])
```

Comment: `Exception.message` was [deprecated long ago](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0352/#retracted-ideas), and removed from Python 3, which is what the OP is using.