# How do I add an exception for invalid input?

Tags: python, exception, input

I am new to Python, so this is probably a dumb question to many here, but in the following code, how would I go about adding an exception, so that should someone enter say a word for instance, that would handle the invalid input and continue to ask, 'Take a guess.'?

```
import random
secretNumber = random.randint(1, 100)
print('I am thinking of a number between 1 and 100.')

for guessesTaken in range(1, 11):
    print('Take a guess.')
    guess = int(input())

    if guess < secretNumber:
        print('Your guess is too low.')
    elif guess > secretNumber:
        print('Your guess is too high.')
    else:
        break   # This condition is the correct guess!

if guess == secretNumber:
    print('Good job! You guessed mu number in ' + str(guessesTaken) + ' guesses!')
else:
    print('Nope. The number I was thinking of was ' + str(secretNumber))
```

Comment: fix your indentation

Comment: Sorry, the formatting did not take? Maybe someone will understand what I am trying to accomplish. I realize this is purely amateur, but I am really trying to learn by doing small stuff.

Comment: I think this post in exception handling might be helpful too: [exception in input in python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24100909/10723535)

Answer (score 3):

I believe what you are trying to do can be accomplished with the input as follows:

```
guess = None
while guess is None:
    try: 
        print('Take a guess.')
        guess = int(input())
    except ValueError:
        pass
```

Comment: Is this the typical error thrown for wrong inputs?

Comment: For built-in methods the ValueError will be thrown when the type matches, but the value is not correct. For this particular example the int method expects a string, gets the string, but the string cannot be converted. 
If you supply say an object of a custom class to the same method, you will get TypeError. 
More on base exception classes: https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#base-classes